# How to increase video memory in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

So I am using a vm for ubuntu and i want to use my full 2GB of video memory from my graphics card, and i can boost the memory to 256MB but its nowhere near what i want. Is there a mod, driver, ANYTHING, that can allow me to get more than a useless 256MB of video memory?

Comment: According to answer in other question 256MB is the maximum. Also see [Superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/293735/is-it-possible-to-assign-more-video-memory-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to assign up to 256 MB of RAM to the virtual graphics driver as shown in my answer to this question:

- [VirtualBox - how to increase video memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587083/virtualbox-how-to-increase-video-memory)

Memory above that value may be useful for 3D-applications. These will make use of the host 3D graphics driver and host VRAM which is passed through to the virtual graphics driver in case 3D capability was enabled in the machine's settings.

So you will use all your host's video ram for 3D rendering in a virtual machine.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. I can only assign up to 256MB but this value is irrelevant because virtualbox will use my graphic cards memory directly anyway?

Comment: @Felipe: yeah that's it.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but what is the setting for then if it is irrelevant?

Comment: @DavidTorrey you may need it in case you don't use the Guest Additions  driver but software rendering on a huge display instead.