# Problem installing virtualbox-guest-dkms

Tags: virtualbox, dkms

I am having a problem installing virtualbox-guest-dkms into Ubuntu 9.04 installed into a VitualBox(6.1.32) VM. (Guest Additions and the Extension Pack have also been installed.) I was following the instructions given on webpage [VirtualBox - how to increase video memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587083/virtualbox-how-to-increase-video-memory) in order to increase the amount of graphics RAM used by the VM.

Everything went fine until I tried to follow the instruction given by user Johan Vijfhuizen with respect to issuing the following instruction within a terminal within virtual Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms & sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

This produced the following result.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install dkms && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fakeroot patch
Suggested packages:
  diff-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed
  dkms fakeroot patch
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 316 not upgraded.
Need to get 275kB of archives.
After this operation, 1053kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get: 1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com jaunty/main dkms 2.0.21.1-0ubuntu3 [57.6kB]
Get: 2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com jaunty/main fakeroot 1.12.1ubuntu1 [117kB]
Get: 3 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com jaunty/main patch 2.5.9-5 [101kB]
Fetched 275kB in 1s (141kB/s) 
Selecting previously deselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 101349 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.0.21.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package fakeroot.
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.12.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package patch.
Unpacking patch (from .../patch_2.5.9-5_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up dkms (2.0.21.1-0ubuntu3) ...
 * Running DKMS auto installation service for kernel 2.6.28-11-generic                                                              [ OK ] 

Setting up fakeroot (1.12.1ubuntu1) ...

Setting up patch (2.5.9-5) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package virtualbox-guest-dkms
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$
```

As can be seen DKMS was installed in virtual Ubuntu but package
virtualbox-guest-dkms could not be found.

In virtual Ubuntu I have edited /etc/apt/sources.list so that packages
could be found. The fact that package DKMS was installed into virtual
Ubuntu shows that the list file was correctly edited.

How do I now get package virtualbox-guest-dkms installed into virtual Ubuntu ?

[For those who may be wondering, I am using such an old version of Ubuntu
because this was the version of Ubuntu that an old 2012 O.U. Sense
microcontroller board was tested against back in the day and I am trying to
replicate the environment that its IDE ran within.]

Stuart

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 9.04 is years past EOL & off-topic, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic